# Doctrine - Remove parent association when deleting child record

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a FileUpload entity that is child of other entities using the following association:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FileUpload", cascade={"persist", "remove"} )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
     protected $image;
```

The FileUpload entity contains various information about an uploaded file as well as a boolean field to mark it for deletion (handled by a checkbox on the form). I am trying to find a good way of managing this deletion process without having to duplicate the code in every entity that has a FileUpload entity.

I tried creating a service tagged with doctrine.event_listener to remove the FileUpload in postUpdate(), however since there is still an association with the parent of the FileUpload this failed. Does anyone know a way of clearing any associations with the FileUpload when it is deleted? Or any other method of handling this process?

Comment: Is ManyToOne correct in your example? You want many entities related to 1 file upload?

Comment: I asked the previous question because that will imply that FileUpload is the owner of the relation, so it should not be deleted when the other entity gets deleted because there could be many more that related to that file upload.

Comment: You are right that there is only one FileUpload per entity. I used ManyToOne because I was under the impression that you can't have multiple OneToOne associations on the same table? For example I have multiple different entities that all have a FileUpload association, would that work if all of those were OneToOne?

Comment: For one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many you can use orphanRemoval option on the owning side of the relation, but there is a catch to this functionality of doctrine, when using refresh on entities. I run into some problems while using this. If you want i can go into details in an answer to your post. Also give you some code example of doing soft delete using orphanRemoval, and fixing the refresh problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm not quite sure I understand. orphanRemoval seems to be used to delete an entity once it's parent removes a reference to it. So in my example say we have a Comment entity that has a OneToOne relationship to a FileUpload. If orphanRemoval was used then when you call $comment->setFileUpload(null) this would remove the link between them as well as the FileUpload. However what I am trying to do is call $entityManager->remove($fileUpload) to delete the FileUpload and subsequently removing the reference to it in the Comment entity. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer. Now I understand your problem.

In the relation you described on the side has to be the owner of the relation. If let's say A is in relation with B and let's say that A is the owner of the relation, that implies that A has control over all the aspects of the relation so B can't be deleted without A say so.

Think about the foreign key relation of a database. The database won't let you delete the line as long as it is part of a relationship and is not the owner of the relation(this being your current problem).

If you get into a place where you need to delete a FileUpload without knowing the Comment that has a relation to it you may have an architectural problem in your application/database design. If you know the Comment that has a relation to the FileUpload at the point that you want to remove the file then orphanRemoval is what you need. The way you remove it is not by asking the Manager to remove it (cause it can't do it without the approval of the owner of the relation, as explained in the example above). Instead, you ask the owner of the relation to removing it something like this

```
//for OneToOne relation
$comment->setFileUpload(null);

//for OneToMany relation
$comment->getFileUpload()->removeElement($fileUpload);
```

After the above statement call flush and it should work. Also for OneToMany make sure that you initialize

```
$this->fileUpload = new ArrayCollection();
```

in the Comment entity constructor.

NOTE1: As mentioned before careful with orphan removal cause it doesn't work as you will expect in relation to refresh function of the manager. After an object was market in doctrine unit of work as an orphan, it will get removed even if you called refresh on it, or it's parent. Found a way around this (using the doctrine onFlush event) but is better to not need this and try to avoid the situation.

NOTE2: orphanRemoval has the effect of hard delete in the database. If as some point you need to do add this code to a doctrine subscriber or onFlush listener

```
public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
{
    foreach ($args->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityDeletions() as $entity) {

        if ($entity instanceof SoftRemovableInterface) {
            $args->getEntityManager()->remove($entity);
            $args->getEntityManager()->persist($entity);
            $entity->remove();
        }

        $args->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->computeChangeSet($args->getEntityManager()->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity)), $entity);
    }
}
```

Where the remove+persist calls are there to take the entity out of the orphan removal list in unit of work (part of the fix for refreshing entities in NOTE1, this is the only place and only way i found that you can stop the removal of an orphan after it was marked as such by doctrine), and $entity->remove(); is the method of the SoftRemovableInterface that handles the soft delete, something like

```
class Comment implements SoftRemovableInterface
{
    /........../
    function remove()
    {
        $this->deleted = true;
    }
}
```

Hope this brings some light to your issue. Happy coding.

Alexandru Cosoi

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Much appreciated.